# Log transformation

Tags: logarithms, transformation

Supose I have a series of numbers from 1 to 10. Their mean value is 5.5. Now supose I apply some transformation like $y=2x+1$. Now their mean value is 12. Now, if I want to get back the original mean, I apply the inverse function, which in this case is $x=(y-1)/2$.

Simple.

Now I want to do the same, but with the $log$ function.

So, I first apply the $y=log(x)$ function and then take the mean. I get a value of 1.51. But then, if I take the inverse $x=e^y$, I get a value of 4.53 and not the original 5.5.

What is happening?

Comment: Have you heard of the AM-GM inequality?

Comment: No, I will check it out. I much apreciated your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first function is linear. Your other one isn't. Calculating the mean is a linear process so it is maintained over your linear transformation while it isn't for a non-linear transformation.

Comment: I disagree: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398150/the-logarithm-is-non-linear-or-isnt-it

Comment: In the context that OP was asking. You'll just confusing him further throwing higher level math at him.

Comment: What the word 'linear' means in middle school evolves to something different at university. Based on the OP's question I was placing him near the beginning of that journey.

Answer (score 0):

Your first function is linear. Therefore,
$$
\frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=1}^{10}f(X_i) = \frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=1}^{10}(2X_i + 1) = 2\frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=1}^{10}X_i + 1 = f\left(\frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=1}^{10}X_i\right).
$$
This doesnt work for the logarithm and the exponential function, since these aren't linear.

Comment: I disagree: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398150/the-logarithm-is-non-linear-or-isnt-it

Answer (score 0):

What you call the *mean* is actually the *arithmetic mean*,
$$
\mathrm{AM}(X) = \dfrac{1}{n} \cdot \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} x_k.
$$
The procedure that you describe in your question is the way the *geometric mean* is computed:
$$
\begin{array}{rcccl}
\exp\left( \mathrm{AM}(\ln(X)) \right)
  &=& \exp\left( \dfrac{1}{n} \cdot \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \ln(x_k) \right) \\
  &=& \exp\left( \dfrac{1}{n} \cdot \ln\left( \prod\limits_{k=1}^{n} x_k \right) \right) \\
  &=& \exp\left( \ln\left( \left( \prod\limits_{k=1}^{n} x_k \right)^{\frac{1}{n}} \right) \right) \\
  &=& \left( \prod\limits_{k=1}^{n} x_k \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}
  &=& \mathrm{GM}(X).
\end{array}
$$

By an inequality known already by the Babylonians and formalized by [Jensen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Finite_form), the geometric mean is always smaller or equal to the arithmetic mean, i.e.
$$
\mathrm{GM}(X) \leq \mathrm{AM}(X).
$$
The mathematical reason for this is that the logarithm is a concave (or negative convex) function. Unfortunately, the concept of *convexity* is often confused with the concept of *non-linearity* (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398150/the-logarithm-is-non-linear-or-isnt-it) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551192/definitions-of-linearity-across-branches-of-mathematics-or-levels-of-math-educ)).